# use in memory file with QML's Image

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

In my application I generate a lot of different images (I keep them as `QImage` objects) and I was wondering if it would be possible to use these objects more or less directly with QML `Image`?
The only option I see is to write them to disk and then pass path to `Image.source`.
Is there any trick to avoid it?

Additional info: apart from static `QIMage`s I also plan to generate gifs and possibly other files (all in memory) which I'll try to use with `AnimatedImage` or `MediaPlayer` so workaround for static image only is not enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [QQuickImageProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html). It allows your QML app to request images/pixmaps from a C++ class that you provide. The data can then come from anywhere you like, including an in-memory QImage. The example provided [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html#an-example) shows how to generate a pixmap on the fly and provide it to a QML Image object.